# Why does Cloudwatch trigger lambda when no events occur?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I was following the AWS tutorials on CloudTrail and CloudWatch and used it to setup a Rule that will trigger a Lambda when a PUT action occurs on an S3 bucket. The lambda will print name of bucket and other details.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

# instantiate an S3 object
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Start processing by looking at Records key-value
    try:
        records = event['Records']
        if len(records) == 0:
            raise Exception("Records was zero!")
        else:
            packet = []
            for row in records:
                msg = "Received event type - {}".format(row["eventName"]) + \
                " caused by user - {}".format(
                    row["userIdentity"]["principalId"]) + \
                    " on bucket - {}".format(row["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]) + \
                    " whose owner is - {}".format(
                        row["s3"]["bucket"]["ownerIdentity"]["principalId"]) + \
                        " The specific object that got put was {}".format(
                            row["s3"]["object"]["key"]
                            )
                print(msg)
                packet.append(
                    {
                        "eventName":row["eventName"],
                        "userIdentity":row["userIdentity"]["principalId"],
                        "bucket":row["s3"]["bucket"]["name"],
                        "bucketOwner":row["s3"]\
                        ["bucket"]["ownerIdentity"]["principalId"],
                        "objectKey":row["s3"]["object"]["key"]
                        }                   )
            return {"statusCode":200, "body":packet}
    except:
        raise Exception("Could not find Records from Events")
```

I noticed that in Cloudwatch logs (under log groups) whenever I placed an file under an S3 bucket, I would see all the activity for the S3 bucket.
But there were instances were the exception -> Could not find Records from Events - were present.

Why is the Lambda being triggered in this case here ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the exception and see what are the exception which are raised.

Comment: The exception raised is “Could not find Records from Events”. This happens when the Records key is not present in the Event keys. The records key holds the data points. The question is why would the lambda get triggered if there are no Records to process

Comment: the Could not find Records from Events exception is printed or raised by you. Can you just check if the exception is keyerror or something else. just change code to excepts Exception as e and print(e).

Comment: It’s a Keyerror - the key was Records. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate-Solution** - If cloudwatch is giving error. You can use notification configuration in s3. This will call the lambda when an object is created in s3.

`Resources:
  bucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref SourceBucket
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
            - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
              Function: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
  BucketPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${SourceBucket}`

Comment: Got it - this will be in response when an object gets created in S3. So when should we use this as opposed to Cloud trail and Cloud watch ?